# Request app level information with Facebook-php-sdk

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hi i am trying to make a request with a app session and its saying this : *"(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint"*. I can make requests only with a app session right?

Below its the code its giving me this error.

```
<?php
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookPermissionException.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $facebook_app_id, $facebook_app_secret);

$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

// To validate the session:
try {
  $session->validate();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
  echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
  // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}

if(isset($session)){
    try {
      $response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/search?q=coimbra&type=event&limit=5000'))->execute();
      $object = $response->getGraphObject();
      echo "done.";
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means you must have a valid USER `access_token` to preform searches. This is because the search results will filter out events (or other content) the user isn't allowed to see, e.g. private events, or closed event. But it also means you find event the user does have permission to see.

In summary, you need to log the user in to get a valid user `access_token` for the search to work.

Comment: what kind of information that i can get with a app level session?